# Class not found when using external library

Tags: php, codeigniter, elastica

I just deployed a fresh version of CI4 and I'm trying to get used to the new features and changes.

I took some legacy code from a CI3 based application and started to upgrade it.

This legacy code uses the Elastica library (to interact with Elasticsearch), so I downloaded the latest Elastica release (https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica), unziped the "src" directory in app/Libraries/Elastica and tried to use it in a controller.

I can't use Composer to deploy the library for obscure security reasons.

Here is how my controller looks :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\Elastica;

class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      // Create a new Elastica instance
      $this->elastica = new Elastica\Client();
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
      $foobar = $this->elastica->getIndex('foobar');
      
      var_dump($foobar);
    }
}
```

But I keep having this error :

```
[Error]

Class "App\Libraries\Elastica\Client" not found

at APPPATH/Controllers/MyController.php:12
```

I have the feeling that I did everything by the book but I am obviously missing something ><

If you could help me finding where I made a mistake, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I opened one of the library files and noticed this at the begining :

`namespace Elastica;`

So I changed the controller this :

`use App\Libraries\Elastica;`

to  this :

`use Elastica;`

Same error.

Comment: Often "I can't use composer for security reasons" means "I can't run composer on the server". The solution is easy, just run it locally and deploy the built files.

Comment: You need to use the library's namespace, which is just `Elastica`. If you for some reason can't use composer to install the library (i don't really see how it's a security concern though, since you can always bundle the vendor folder as a part of your application), you can still store the files in a vendor folder and create a [custom PSR-4 loader](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md).

Comment: As @Chris Haas pointed out, I can't run composer on the server, everything has to be bundled in the application. I'll try to run composer in a dev environnement. But I'm still confused with the errors I'm getting...

Comment: You must either bring that class into scope using `use Elastica\Client`, or you must say `new \Elastica\Client()`. Another alternative that some people like is aliases, which could be `use Elastica\Client as ECClient;` and then `new ECClient()`.

Comment: I did try all the possible combinations, nothing work to call this class, I'm going to try with composer ><